# How might humans and their civilisations deal with living in a narrow band between a hot  face and cold ❄️ face of a planet?

Tags: society, humans, civilization, alternate-worlds

[Inspired by this answer.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/244780/102986)

How would the humans and their civilisations deal with things like:

- The almost 1D direction of travel within a habitat zone
- The limited liveable space
- Having to go near the hot and cold extremes for resources
- Trying to explain how this happened in religions, spiritual beliefs, and various theories
- Having to deal with the lifeforms evolved to deal with the paradigm of hot and cold on the planet's liveable portion
- Being almost entirely glacier  meltwater habitat dwellers, which is almost like a coastal habitat for our world, except it is freshwater. This is easy to live in, but will give less specialisation prospects for civilisations to utilise. It would also need a lot of boats .
- The high likelihood that it is a one nation world, as there is so little space to begin (only lightly on this as it is mostly its own question)

Comment: I think you should narrow down the focus of this question and break it down into several Q&A, one for each aspect. Also, check this answer, about farming food on the run: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/58805/353

Comment: "The almost 1D direction of travel within a habitat zone" describes Egypt. Their civilization did just fine for thousands of years. As for there being only so little space to live on, the livable band may be quite narrow, let's say 400 km, but it is *very* long; there may be room for 4 countries the size of the USA (which is a ginormous country on Earth), or 25 countries the size of France (which is a large country on European scales).

Comment: Egypt. Also steep-sided Swiss valleys. I remember someone tried to find the families of people listed in a 14th century document, and almost half of them were still there. 1D communities seem to be more stable then 2D communities in the plains..

Comment: VTC:Needs More Focus. You are allowed to ask one and only one question. Per the [tour], Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. Per the [help/dont-ask], this series of questions exceeds the book rule (too broad).